# Sending Email with Python 3.2, Virtualenv, and Django

Tags: python, django, email

As part of a school project, I am trying to send email via gmail.
We are using django in a virtualenv, because we are using python packages that are not currently installed (mostly Pillow).
The email configuration in settings.py looks like so:

```
#Email Config
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'validEmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Apasswd'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'validEmail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

This configuration works fine outside of the virtualenv, but when running inside the virtualenv, I get this:

```
[Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

What can I do to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the destination location is reachable (smtp.gmail.com)? It could be a network issue.

Comment: I am sure that smtp.google.com is reachable from the computers we are running on. Before we switched to the virtualenv, we could send email with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Drop everything related to your smtp configuration and try this:

```
## Email
## GMail
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your-email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your-password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_FROM = 'your-email@gmail.com'
```

now go to `python manage.py shell` and do this

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'your-email@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

if `to@example.com` receives the email, everything is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, when I try this, I get the same error as above.